# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, css, joomla

I have a joomla template on my website, integrated with SP Page Builder. I have not tampered with any wrong setting, but suddenly I started to receive the following error:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/interpr1/public_html/lms/components/com_sppagebuilder/layouts/addon/css.php on line 82

The error occurs when I go to the frontend of my website to edit the page.

I went to the CSS file and on line 82, here is what I found:

```
$addon_css .= (isset($addon->settings->global_border_radius) && $addon->settings->global_border_radius) ? "border-radius: " . $addon->settings->global_border_radius . "px;\n" : "";
```

I am not at all familiar with PHP, and that is why I could not benefit from the solutions given to similar errors reported on this website.